# I want to replace H2 tag by link with Javascript

Tags: javascript, hyperlink

I want to replace H2 tag by link with Javascript.

So the tag looks like:

```
<h2>Categories</h2>
```

I expect as output:

```
<a href="#">Categories</a>
```

How can I do that? Is it possible?

The code I tried, but with no success:

```
$("#categories").find("h2").replaceWith($('<a href="#"></a>'));
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/replaceWith

Comment: Please share the code you have tried and we can help improve upon that.

Comment: I updated the topic with the code I've tried.

Comment: So you are using jQuery??

Comment: Please provide more code so we can try to figure out what your problem is?

Comment: The code that "epascarello" provided it worked. Thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using replaceWith and createElement.

```js
const h2s = document.querySelectorAll("h2");
h2s.forEach(function (elem) {
  const anchor = document.createElement("a");
  anchor.href = "#";
  anchor.textContent = elem.textContent;
  elem.replaceWith(anchor);
});
```

```html
<h2>Hello</h2>
<h2>There</h2>
```

Comment: I cannot vote, but THANK YOU. It worked perfectly!